# Server not able to listen to the client?

Tags: python, sockets

I am new to Socket programming and trying to run a simple client-server code.

server.py

```
host=""                
port=80                   

from socket import *                
s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))                 

s.listen(1)                          

print "Listening for connections.. "
q,addr=s.accept()   

data=input("Enter data to be send:  ")                                             
q.send(data)                       
s.close()
```

client.py

```
host = "52.170.194.29"
port=80               

from socket import *             

s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)      
s.connect((host,port))          

msg=s.recv(1024)            

print ("Message from server : " + msg.strip().decode('ascii'))

s.close()                            
# End of code
```

---

Both scripts compile successfully. As such, server.py goes blank or does nothing after printing `waiting for connections` and similar happens for client.py.

Can I have some idea where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Are client and server on the same LAN?

Comment: Is your server really running on the www port of public internet address 52.170.194.29? Because a real web server wouldn't send you anything until you tell it what, which would explain the client stopping.

Comment: @YannVernier, Its actually the azure VM ip.

Comment: @magicleon No, server is azure's VM.

Comment: Can you ping it from your shell? I believe that's not reachable, maybe you need to open ports

Comment: @magicleon, I am able to telnet 52.170.194.29 80. It works